# DOMDocument::saveHTML меняет href у ссылки. Как исправить?

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
$content = '<a href="[[~999]]">ссылка</a>';

// Исправляем ошибки кодировки
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
// ВАЖНО! Добавляем fakeroot (тег div), так как без него иногда может ломаться верстка. Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479994/php-domdocument-savehtml-breaks-format .
$dom->loadHTML('<div>' . $content . '</div>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$root = $dom->documentElement;

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    $href = urldecode($href);
    $link->setAttribute('href', $href);
    $link->setAttribute('data-href', $href);
    $test = $dom->saveHTML($link);
    echo $test;
    break;
}
```

В итоге выводится такое значение:

`<a href="%5B%5B~999%5D%5D" data-href="[[~999]]">ссылка</a>`

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы href был такой же, как data-href? Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
$dom->saveXML();
```

Вместо

```
$dom->saveHTML();
```